# generate UUID automatically for all records in Cassandra for an existing dataset

Tags: cassandra, uuid

I have an existing dataset with around 700000 records in a CSV format. I have imported that data file into apache Cassandra table. The problem is

primary key. How can I automatically generate (upsert) uuid into my primary key column for all of my records?
I am using Cassandra 3.10.

Comment: What are you using to import the records into Cassandra? And do the existing records that you are importing already have a primary key?

Comment: I used the COPY command to import data into Cassandra table. The existing records have the auto-increment primary key. But apache Cassandra does not support auto-increment primary key. So I decided to drop that column.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if you're using the `COPY` command you don't really have any options for generating `UUIDs` on the fly for your rows. I think you really have two options, both of which involve doing things programmatically to one extent or another:

1. Do some pre-processing on your CSV file to generate and add a `UUID` to each row, writing out a new file with that additional field and `UUID` value for each row. It should be pretty straightforward to process the file, line by line, and generate those values using a small Python script or something similar. Then you can use the `COPY` command like before to import the data into Cassandra.
2. Since you're already going to be writing some code, skip using the `COPY` command altogether and just write the code in Python (or Java or your language of choice) to read the file, parse each CSV line into values, generate a UUID for that row, and then `INSERT` the data into Cassandra using the appropriate driver for the programming language you're using.

If you decide to go with option 2, you'll find a list of the [DataStax drivers for Cassandra towards the bottom of this page](http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/current.html), along with documentation for how to use them. Hope that helps!